# Какая разница по потреблению ресурсов между ubuntu server и ubuntu desktop и windows server web?

Tags: windows, linux

1. Ubuntu server 14.04.
2. Ubuntu desktop 14.04.
3. Windows Server 2008 Web

Cколько сама система будет отъедать оперативной памяти? Понятно, что первая меньше всего, но насколько меньше, можно по всем трем дать примерные оценки?

Comment: как то плохо поставлен вопрос. Если Вам нужен сервер, то смотреть на декстопную версию не нужно. Если нужен декстоп, то смотреть на серверную версию не нужно.

Если нужны программы, которые только в винде работают (iss сервер, mssql) то опять же, ответ очевиден. Если нужны линуксовые утилиты - ответ снова очевиден.


Если же Вы переживаете за память, то ставьте gentoo/Arch и тюнингуйте до последнего бита.

Comment: @KoVadim,поставить можно на любую из трех, так как цена одинаковая и нужные приложения кроссплатформенные. Конечно, упор на то, чтобы больше памяти оставалось, но при этом хочу знать насколько больше её останется, чтобы знать  стоит ли экономить или взять гуи. Или десктоп версия для сервия - извращение?

Comment: Декстоп версия для сервера - не нужна. Для этого специально есть серверная (хотя разница между ними - никакой, просто разный набор софта, и, возможно, немного подтюнингованная система. Умелый админ легко серверный линукс переделает в декстопный и наоборот).

В целом, ставьте нормальный дебиан и не парьтесь.

Comment: @KoVadim, по потреблению RAM есть разница? Если в дебиан меньше, то почему? Интересует начальное состояние после установки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В зависимости, что будет крутиться на этом GUI. О последнем ничего не скажу, а вот о первых двух немножко расскажу.

Если используется для клиент-серверного решения, то GUI видно только тому, кто сидит на нем. Пользователям будут высылаться такие же данные, как и без GUI. Даже если убрать всех владельцев, чтобы не сидели "в окнах", то нагрузка будет все равно чуть выше, чем у серверной версии. Примерно сказать не смогу, сколько выходит, т.к. такие опыты я не проводил.
Если выражать в цифрах и очень условно, то:

- Server 256 мб,
- Desktop +10% выше от предыдущего.

Comment: Вообще-то на вопрос о том, сколько места занимает система (Linux) однозначно ответить сложно. 

Это сильно зависит от ее состояния. 

На одной из машин (ubuntu) у меня во время загрузки, сразу после распределения памяти:

     dmesg | grep Memory
     [    0.000000] Memory: 1006764K/1048120K available (6540K  kernel code, 641K rwdata, 2764K rodata, 876K init, 924K bss, 41356K  reserved, 135112K highmem)


на другой системе немного иначе  
(но похоже, а места тут мало).


А потом стартуют демоны и ... (почитайте, например, [здесь](http://markelov.blogspot.ru/2009/01/linux-procmeminfo.html)).

Comment: место? Я описывал RAM, а не занимаемое место на HDD(SSD)

Comment: @lolokot, это место в RAM (присмотритесь внимательней). 

Суть в том, что это (к highmem, конечно, не относится) невыгружаемая память. Но, безусловно, не вся, которая станет невыгружаемой за время жизни системы.

Answer (score 1):

На ubuntu desktop расходы на unity от 300 до 600 mb RAM будет тратиться.

Comment: @dimka3210, и как Вы это вычисляете?

Вот я, если откровенно, не могу понять, куда надо отнести пару физических страниц из libc.so с какой-нибудь printf(), если в данный момент, с одной стороны, они приписаны к десяткам процессов, а с другой - к ним не было обращения уже несколько секунд и они запросто могут оказаться в free-списке.

Comment: Был опыт по неопытности. ) Ради легкой настройки вместо сервера зафигачил desktop. И эмперическим путем выяснил именно эти цифры. Меньше 300МБ никогда не было.

Comment: @dimka3210, Вы смотрели командой free?

У меня сейчас 64-бит десктоп (правда не unity, а xubuntu) показывает


    avp@avp-ubu1:~$ free -m
                 total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
    Mem:          7985       1308       6676          5        223        581
    -/+ buffers/cache:        502       7482
    Swap:         2714          0       2714

Comment: @dimka3210 эмпирическим

Comment: @avp, не совсем понимаю, что именно вы этим хотели показать.

    dlarchikov@sys-ws-60:~/PhpstormProjects/b2bcenter$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
    Память:      15379       8314       7064        129        266       3133
    -/+ буферы/кэш:       4913      10465
    Swap:        15551          0      15551


Ну, у меня вот так. Я думаю, было бы правильнее на одном железе сначала с юнити поменять, на пустом, а потом без неё.

@Etki, спасибо, постоянно забываю, как это слово пишется.)

Comment: @dimka3210, это была просто иллюстрация вывода free.

Вообще-то вопрос был как Вы вычисляли размер unity. Ответ надо понимать такой -- сравнил вывод free (или чего другого?) на компе с ней и без сразу после загрузки.

Я же (тоже вообще) говорю о том, что на самом деле этот размер зависит от ситуации (страницы вроде бы относящиеся к unity и ставшие неактивными будут вытесняться из памяти при необходимости. Просто никто ведь не меряет память при высокой загрузке (да и весьма это поблематично)).

Резюме -- точно предсказать сколько нужно памяти -- не удастся.

Comment: Смотрел на htop в основном.